# How to handle results of multiple async callbacks in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I'm working on a scenario in Node which involves multiple `async.map` calls, one of which is nested in an `_.map` function as I need access to nested arrays. I'm struggling to properly combine the results of these calls into an array which I return in the end.

More specifics on the scenario:

I start with a `userId` and query my games db to find all `games` which this userId is associated with. I pull `gameId` and `description` for each game.

I then query the `gameId` of each of these games to find all `userId`s associated with each game. I filter the original `userId` out of these results.

Next I query my users db for each of these `userId`s in order to get details such as user `email` and `name`. (Note: this is where `_.map` comes into play as the `userId`s are nested in an array of arrays; each inner array representing a game).

The last step, and where I'm struggling, is how to combine these results and return them. My final desired array looks like the below. An array of game objects. Each game object has a `gameId`, `description`, and `users` property. `users` is an array of users associated with that game and has `id`, `email`, and `name` properties.

```
[
  {
    gameId: 'dfh48643hdgf',
    description: 'lorem ipsum...',
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        email: 'test@example.com',
        name: 'John Doe'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        email: 'sample@example.com',
        name: 'Jane Smith'
      }, ...
    ]
  }, ...
]
```

Below is the code I currently have (Note: this code block is actually part of a larger `async.series` call):

```
sharedGames: function(next) {
  db.games.index({userId: userId},
    function(err, gamesData) {
      if (err) {
        logger.warn('Error retrieving games for userId %d', userId, err);
        next(err, null);
      } else {
        gamesData = _.map(gamesData, function(game) {
          return {
            gameId: game.id,
            description: game.description,
            users: []
          };
        });
        async.map(gamesdata,
          function(item, callback) {
            db.gameDetails.getGameUsers({gameId: item.gameId},
              function(err, users) {
                if (err) {
                  callback(err, null);
                } else {
                  callback(null, _.without(users.userIds, Number(userId)));
                }
              }
            );
          },
          function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
              next(null, null);
            } else {
              var flattenedResults = _.chain(results)
                .flatten()
                .uniq()
                .value();
              async.map(flattenedResults, function(user, callback) {
                db.users.getById(user, function(err, userDetails) {
                  if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                  } else {
                    callback(null, _.pick(userDetails, 'id', 'email', 'name'));
                  }
                });
              }, function(err, users) {
                if (err) {
                  next(null, null);
                } else {
                  _.each(results, function(result, index) {
                    _.each(result, function(user) {
                      var customerDetails = _.find(customers, function(u) {
                        return u.id === user;
                      });
                      gamesData[index].users.push(userDetails);
                    });
                  });
                  console.log(gamesData);
                  next(null, gamesdata);
                }
              });
            }
          }
        );
        next(null, []);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I'd personally spend more time figuring out how to write a single query to get all the needed data and make just one async db request.

Comment: @slebetman, agreed that would be a better approach. The problem is that what I've simplified in the code posted above as db calls are actually calls to secure internal API endpoints. So unfortunately the opportunity to create a robust query is not available in this case.

Comment: @MattDionis have you checked `async.auto`? This method has helped me in the past to accomplish something similar to what you're describing. https://github.com/caolan/async#auto

Comment: @slebetman, so I made some improvements to my code and am now very close. The `next(null, gamesData);` line is now triggering a `Callback was already called` error, but I'm not sure how else to get my `gamesData` returned.

Answer (score 0):

So you can definitely accomplish what you're describing with `async.auto`. Check this from their docs:

```
async.auto({
get_data: function(callback){
    console.log('in get_data');
    // async code to get some data
    callback(null, 'data', 'converted to array');
},
make_folder: function(callback){
    console.log('in make_folder');
    // async code to create a directory to store a file in
    // this is run at the same time as getting the data
    callback(null, 'folder');
},
write_file: ['get_data', 'make_folder', function(callback, results){
    console.log('in write_file', JSON.stringify(results));
    // once there is some data and the directory exists,
    // write the data to a file in the directory
    callback(null, 'filename');
}],
email_link: ['write_file', function(callback, results){
    console.log('in email_link', JSON.stringify(results));
    // once the file is written let's email a link to it...
    // results.write_file contains the filename returned by write_file.
    callback(null, {'file':results.write_file, 'email':'user@example.com'});
}]
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log('err = ', err);
    console.log('results = ', results);
});
```

So if you follow the same approach, you can get the array of game objects by injecting more info every call. You can also use `async.waterfall`. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! So I made some improvements to my code and am now very close. The `next(null, gamesData);` line is now triggering a `Callback was already called` error, but I'm not sure how else to get my `gamesData` returned.

Comment: @MattDionis I think it's that last `next(null, []);` not sure if it should be there :/

Comment: Bingo! It was that last `next(null, []);`